# Add storage to Azure resource manager

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-resource-manager

Is it possible to add storage to a resource groups?
IIRC my storage group was created automatically when I used the 'old' version of the portal.
I can see my domain and VM in the group, but no storage. How do I add it?

Answer (score 2):

You can create the storage account with in a resource group by using following template via ARM API or Powershell as well:

```
{
"$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2014-04-01-preview/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "name": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "location": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "accountType": {
        "type": "string"
    }
},
"resources": [
    {
        "apiVersion": "2014-06-01",
        "name": "[parameters('name')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.ClassicStorage/StorageAccounts",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "properties": {
            "accountType": "[parameters('accountType')]"
        }
    }
]}
```

Comment: Did you actually try that?  I'm guessing you'll get an error.  *Eventually* this will work, but currently only the Azure portal can use the ARM API for storage.  See [this comment thread](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-preview-portal-using-resource-groups/#comment-1739284751) for details.

Comment: Yeah, that's because they just added that functionality 2 days ago: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/04/29/build-2015-azure-storage-announcements/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean storage account, you can create a storage account within a resource group in the [preview portal](https://portal.azure.com).  You cannot yet do it via the ARM API or Powershell though (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27796995/310446)).