# Azure Resource Manager microsoft.classicstorage/storageAccounts no registered resource provider

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-resource-manager, azure-cli

I am getting an error when Azure Resource Manager (ARM) is deploying my template on Azure. In the Resource Group events pane I get an error for the storage account creation of:

statusMessage:{"error":{"code":"NoRegisteredProviderFound","message":"No registered resource provider found for location 'Australia Southeast' and API version '2014-11-01'."}}

I am using the Azure xPlat CLI and can confirm with the command `azure location list` that the storageAccounts resource is available in Australia Southeast. The resource in the template is:

```
{
        "apiVersion": "2014-11-01",
        "name": "[variables('storageName')]",
        "type": "microsoft.classicstorage/storageAccounts",
        "location": "[variables('location')]"
}
```

I have tried this with different values for the apiVersion from the list at [Service Management Versioning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg592580.aspx)

Does anyone know if it is the api version? Or the Location that is the issue? And if either, is there any way to debug this further than the error message on the portal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating storage accounts via Azure Resource Manager is not available yet.  A rule of thumb is to check the output of `Get-AzureResourceGroupGalleryTemplate` - if there's no template for a service, then it is not available to ARM yet.

[More discussion](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f40b24dc-8c82-411e-871a-be3710743ec1/unable-to-create-azure-virtual-machine-using-resource-group-template?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows) on this topic in the MSDN forums.

**Edit**
This functionality was just announced: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/04/29/build-2015-azure-storage-announcements/

Comment: Using the xplat-cli for the command `azure location list` has the storage accounts and valid regions as available though. Is this a bug in the xplat-cli or just being a bit eager maybe?

Comment: `azure location list` shows all the regions where services are available via any method, including the portal.  So you can create storage accounts via the portal, but not via ARM.

Comment: No worries. Is there a rough timeframe anywhere on adding/extending these to be available via ARM?

Comment: I wish there was :)  I would assume sooner rather than later, but you never really know.

Answer (score 2):

This issue will be fixed in the new version of xplat cli 0.8.14 which should be out by Monday Jan 26, 2015.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the location i.e. 'Australia Southeast'.

For now, The provided location 'Australia Southeast' is not permitted for this resource provider 'Microsoft.ClassicStorage/storageAccounts'.

you can fetch the supported location by using the following cmdlets:

PS C:> Get-AzureLocation | Where-Object Name -EQ 'Microsoft.ClassicStorage/storageAccounts'

The supported locations for the storage accounts are as follows:

East Asia, Southeast Asia, East US, East US 2, West US, North Central US, South Central US, Central US, North Europe, West Europe, Japan East, Japan West, Brazil South

for more information, Please refer this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn654582.aspx.

Hope this helps.

Thanks.

Comment: Using the xplat-cli for the command `azure location list` has the storage accounts and valid regions for Australia as available though. Not sure for the difference between PS and xplat-cli...